# Environment.NewLine Not working in one textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Forgive me if there is answer for this, I could not find one that fits this situation.

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms site using VB.Net in Code Behind.

There is a page that loads data from a SQL DB. Everything is working fine except for one text box. I get all the data but it is not formatting like the other text box's.

Here is the code that IS working:

```
ASP.Net Textbox - Root Cause
<asp:TextBox ID="txbRootCause" runat="server" CssClass="text-primary" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Width="400px" />

VB.Net Code Behind
Case "rc"
    For i As Integer = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
        sectionString = sectionString & sqlDT.Rows(i)("entrydatetime") & " " & sqlDT.Rows(i)("submittedby") & " " & sqlDT.Rows(i)("rootcause") &  Environment.NewLine
    Next
    txbRootCause.Text = sectionString

String that is built
"3/19/2018 14:37:00 Z.German Admin Root Cause" & vbCrLf & "3/19/2018 14:54:00 L.Ludwig Adding root cause because Zach said so." & vbCrLf
```

It builds a text string and assigns it to a text box. Notice that the string has an Environment.NewLine at the end so that each entry starts on a new line. It works fine in five other text boxes. (Different names on the text boxes)

Now this is the code that is NOT working

```
ASP.Net Textbox - Reviewed
<asp:TextBox ID="txbReviews" runat="server" CssClass="text-primary" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" Width="400px" />

VB.Net Code Behind
Case "rv"
    For i As Integer = 0 To sqlDT.Rows.Count - 1
        sectionString = sectionString & sqlDT.Rows(i)("entrydatetime") & " " & sqlDT.Rows(i)("submittedby") & " " & sqlDT.Rows(i)("reviewed") & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    txbReviews.Text = sectionString

String that is built
"3/19/2018 14:37:00 Z.German Admin Review Example" & vbCrLf & "3/19/2018 L.Ludwig Reviewing :-) " & vbCrLf
```

It builds the exact same type of string of text with the new line in it but when it displays the new line is not put in the code.

Here is an image of the two text boxes.

[image]

Notice the two distinct lines of text. Now here is the one that is not working:

[image]

Notice that the new line is not working in the reviewed box. What am I missing? I can't seem to find a reason for this not to work.

Anyone see where I might have screwed up?

Comment: make use of textarea that might resolve issue

Comment: @PranayRana a multiline asp.net TextBox control does render to a textarea html element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a server side issue but an Internet Explorer one. Internet Explorer processes the `white-space` differently. I bet you have `white-space: normal;` there.

[image: Normal]

You could try different options, but `white-space: pre-line;` does the job:

[image: preline]

Comment: I see what you are saying but I do not have that in my CSS file. What really is confusing me is the fact that the same code routine works for the other 5 text boxs without a problem. I will try your solution and update when tested.

Comment: The problem is that the textbox you have problems with is wrapping the lines whereas the others aren't.

Comment: You could add a CSS class to those text areas and force the white-space. But it's definitely a style issue.

Comment: Added inline style as hardkoded suggested and it is now working.
Thanks for the help!